# SQLite - Column not creating

Tags: android, sqlite

I have read the previous posts on this already and none have provided a working solution (restarting emulator, commas, spacing tweaks).

Creating a simple SQLite database, but receiving the same error each time I run it;

```
05-12 04:06:17.541    2063-2063/com.disclosure_scots.disclosure_scots E/SQLiteLog﹕ (1) table login has no column named tel_no
05-12 04:06:17.542    2063-2063/com.disclosure_scots.disclosure_scots E/SQLiteDatabase﹕ Error inserting email=test@email.com name=test name tel_no=1231234123 created_at=2015-05-12 06:06:19 uid=55517c3b97a8b8.60336236
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table login has no column named tel_no (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO login(email,name,tel_no,created_at,uid) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1469)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1341)
            at com.disclosure_scots.disclosure_scots.SQLiteHandler.addUser(SQLiteHandler.java:85)
            at com.disclosure_scots.disclosure_scots.RegisterActivity$2.onResponse(RegisterActivity.java:151)
            at com.disclosure_scots.disclosure_scots.RegisterActivity$2.onResponse(RegisterActivity.java:128)
            at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:60)
            at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:30)
            at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:99)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

My code, I have tried this with different spacing to no avail;

```
// Login Table Columns names
    private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    private static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
    private static final String KEY_EMAIL = "email";
    private static final String KEY_UID = "uid";
    private static final String KEY_CREATED_AT = "created_at";
    private static final String KEY_TEL_NO = "tel_no";

    public SQLiteHandler(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    // Creating Tables
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String CREATE_LOGIN_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_LOGIN + "("
                + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "
                + KEY_NAME + " TEXT, "
                + KEY_EMAIL + " TEXT UNIQUE, "
                + KEY_UID + " TEXT, "
                + KEY_CREATED_AT + " TEXT, "
                + KEY_TEL_NO + " TEXT " + ")";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_LOGIN_TABLE);

        Log.d(TAG, "Database tables created");
    }

    // Upgrading database
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // Drop older table if existed
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_LOGIN);

        // Create tables again
        onCreate(db);
    }
```

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Have you uninstalled your app? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21881992/when-is-sqliteopenhelper-oncreate-onupgrade-run

Comment: Try increasing the database version?

Comment: Looks like you never ran your onCreate/onUpgrade method

Comment: Where are you inserting data into your table?

Answer (score 0):

Right, despite restarting the emulator it appears a second app I had running in another Android Studio window, using the same db name, was booting up each time i ran the main app.

Thanks for answering guys, sorry to waste your time.